# How can I set a standard gradient on a listbox for different colored listboxitems?

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, gradient, listboxitem

I have a listbox with different colored listbox items, each containing text.  I would like to apply a standard gradient pattern of light to dark from top to bottom on each of them.

I am able to do this with a specific color in C# by applying a Style to the listbox containing GradientStops.  However I don't want a single color gradient applied to the entire listbox.  I am looking for something along the lines of "Start X% lighter than the declared color and end up at the declared color".

I've also considered individually styling each listboxitem with its own color gradient, but was unable to find a way to do this.

The listbox is defined in the xaml, so the solution can be xaml or C#. Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I remember doing something like this by...

1. Having a bright background.
2. Binding the base color to both stops.
3. Lowering the opacity on the first stop by changing the alpha channel via a [converter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter.aspx).

To apply such a style to each individual item use the [`ItemContainerStyle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemcontainerstyle.aspx).

Comment: Ok, I'm going to explore this and report back.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                    <Border Margin="5,5,7,7" Background="WhiteSmoke" 
                            BorderBrush="#FF444444" BorderThickness="1" Padding="5">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" Width="150">
                      <TextBlock.Background>
                        <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="1,1">
                          <GradientStop Color="Yellow" Offset="0.0" />
                          <GradientStop Color="Red" Offset="0.25" />
                          <GradientStop Color="Blue" Offset="0.75" />
                          <GradientStop Color="LimeGreen" Offset="1.0" />
                        </LinearGradientBrush>
                      </TextBlock.Background>
                    </TextBlock>
                </Border>
            </DataTemplate>
```

Comment: No, "multi-colored" listboxitems may have been the wrong way to put it.  Let's just say I have individual red, yellow and blue listboxitems.  I want a top to bottom gradient, lighter to darker, applied to each.